# Wordpress: Exclude the post thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the code below to get the attached images for each post in my theme for use in a slideshow. It works great in that it is able to retrieve all of the attached images, but it also includes [the post thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

So my question is, is there a way to exclude *just* the `featured_image` but display the rest of the images?

**PHP**

```
function bdw_get_images($postId) {

$iPostID = $postId;
$arrImages =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $iPostID );

    if($arrImages) {

        $arrKeys = array_keys($arrImages);

        foreach($arrImages as $oImage) {
            $arrNewImages[] = $oImage;
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrNewImages) - 1; $i++) {
            for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($arrNewImages) - 1; $j++) {
                if((int)$arrNewImages[$j]->menu_order > (int)$arrNewImages[$j + 1]->menu_order) {
                    $oTemp = $arrNewImages[$j];
                    $arrNewImages[$j] = $arrNewImages[$j + 1];
                    $arrNewImages[$j + 1] = $oTemp;
                }
            }
        }

        $arrKeys = array();

        foreach($arrNewImages as $oNewImage) {
            $arrKeys[] = $oNewImage->ID;
        }

        $iNum = $arrKeys[0];

        foreach( $arrKeys as $key) {
            $sImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($key);
            $sImgString = '<img src="' . $sImageUrl . '" alt="Thumbnail Image" />';
            echo $sImgString;
        }
    }
}

bdw_get_images($post->ID);
```

Comment: If the featured image index is the same at all posts, maybe you should just ignore it by php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get post thumbnail(if any) by get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) function and check against it in the last loop.
So the last loop should look like this:

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $iPostID );
foreach( $arrKeys as $key) {
    if( $key == $post_thumbnail_id )
        continue;
    $sImageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($key);
    $sImgString = '<img src="' . $sImageUrl . '" alt="Thumbnail Image" />';
    echo $sImgString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check to see if this works as soon as possible.